# calculate total distance covered in KMs provided a list of coordinates in Python

Tags: python, gps, coordinates

I have given a list of coordinates with longitude and latitude.

```
[[-8.610876000000001, 41.14557], [-8.610858, 41.145579000000005], [-8.610903, 41.145768], [-8.610444, 41.146190999999995], [-8.609445000000001, 41.146758], [-8.608896, 41.147118], [-8.608968, 41.147127], [-8.608707, 41.147532000000005], [-8.608347, 41.148117000000006], [-8.608149, 41.148351000000005], [-8.608041, 41.148576000000006], [-8.607654, 41.14926], [-8.607348000000002, 41.149899000000005], [-8.607393, 41.149899000000005], [-8.607357, 41.149962], [-8.606817, 41.150979], [-8.606358, 41.151914999999995], [-8.605719, 41.152788], [-8.604981, 41.153318999999996], [-8.604783, 41.154345], [-8.604828, 41.154372], [-8.604801, 41.155353], [-8.604648000000001, 41.156774999999996], [-8.604522, 41.158197], [-8.604513, 41.159943000000005], [-8.604377999999999, 41.16055500000001], [-8.604377999999999, 41.1606], [-8.604369, 41.160644999999995], [-8.60436, 41.160807], [-8.604162, 41.161176], [-8.604126, 41.161248], [-8.60409, 41.16129300000001], [-8.60409, 41.161266000000005], [-8.604108, 41.161239], [-8.604126, 41.161194], [-8.604135, 41.161275], [-8.60391, 41.162048999999996], [-8.602929000000001, 41.162832], [-8.602551000000002, 41.163111], [-8.601894, 41.163597]]
```

*I need to calculate total distance traveled in Kilometers.*
I thought of using the popular technique given in stackoverlflow

```
dlon = lon2 - lon1
dlat = lat2 - lat1

a = sin(dlat / 2)**2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2)**2
c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))

distance = R * c
```

I tried -

```
totaldistance = 0
for i in range(1, len(coordinates)):
    totaldistance += distance(coordinates[0], coordinates[i])
```

But how should I do with a list of coordinates given which specifies where all exactly the object roam around.
So like total traveled.
Since I am new to Python, I am getting stuck

Comment: what does *which specifies where all exactly the object roam around.* mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the total of all the calculations unpack and sum:

```
tot = sum(distance(lat, lng)) for lat,lng in coords)
```

If you want each pair of sublists passed i.e `l[0],l[1]`, `l[2],l[3]` etc.. :

```
it = iter(coords)
tot = sum(distance(lat, lng)) for lat,lng in zip(it,it))
```

If you want to sum every pair `l[0],l[1]`, `l[1],l[2]`etc..:

```
tot = sum(distance(l[i],l[i+1]) for i in range(len(l)-1))
```

Comment: distance takes 2 coordinates , (lat,long,lat,long) , so the method won't work or I am missing something

Comment: so you want to pair each two sublists?

Comment: my method wants 2 coordinates which gives 2 separate pairs of (long,lat), so that distance could be calculated between 2. I want the total distance travelled, based on the coordinates given , so [A,B,C,D] , so total distance travel will be like A->B->C->D

Comment: you mean `[-8.610876000000001, 41.14557], [-8.610858, 41.145579000000005]` should be passed to the function?

Comment: yeah I was expecting that , but thats how i wrote the method, but I am expecting and better way to do that

Comment: should `[-8.610858, 41.145579000000005], [-8.610903, 41.145768]` also be passed or only every two pairs not overlapping?

Comment: Then the last genexp will be what you want

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear what you're asking, but I think you want to sum up the total distance traveled.  That's pretty easy to accomplish, and you were pretty close (assuming that your distance function works properly).  You just have to make a slight change to your loop:

```
totaldistance = 0
for i in range(len(coordinates) - 1):
    totaldistance += distance(coordinates[i], coordinates[i + 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now you are adding the distance from 0 to 1, 0 to 2, etc. Do you want to get total distance traveled, as in 0 to 1, 1 to 2, 2 to 3, ...? If so try editing the totaldistance loop:

```
totaldistance = 0
for i in range(0, len(coordinates)-1):
    totaldistance += distance(coordinates[i], coordinates[i+1])
```